# Backup-SPFarm or Backup-SPSite to backup a site collection and it's content database

Tags: 2010, powershell, administration, site-collection, backup

Should I use Backup-SPFarm or Backup-SPSite to backup a site collection with it's content database? Dont both of them backs up with it's content database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Backup-SPSite**

- You can run it only for a site collection but it doesn't offer any backups at the Content Databases level.
- If you want to back up multiple site collections then you will have to run it each time.
- Backup-SPSite offers more level of granulity and scope which Backup-Farm doesn't offer.

**Backup-SPFarm**

- For backing up all the content Databases, web applications, service application etc. you may use Backup-SPFarm because the scope is beyond any individual site collection.
- It can't target the individual site collection within a content database, which makes it different from Backup-SPSite cmdlt.

If you have only single site collection to back up, then go for Back-SPSite

Comment: Thank you Falak. I think the keyword is "but it doesn't offer any backups at the Content Databases level." Now it makes sense why answer was was wrong. Thanks

Comment: Do not fully agree with "doesn't offer any backups at the Content Databases level" since the content is stored in a specific content database and that content will be saved as part of the backup so while yes, the full content database might not be saved if it's shared with other site collections, the relevant part will be. So for me, Backup-SPSite is enough. Cheers